# Intercept long clicks mac os x

Tags: macos

I'm very new to Mac OS X development. Would it be possible to create an app that performs an action when the user `long-presses` on a filename in `Finder`. I have no idea how one would intercept the `long-press`...

Answer (score 0):

```
// ---------------------------------

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

// ---------------------------------

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return  YES;
}

// ---------------------------------

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

// ---------------------------------

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint location = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    // Do some test to see if we should handle the mouse down and set an instance BOOL variable myMouseClick (that mouseUp can also see)

    if(myMouseClick)
    {
        time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent () // time is also an instance variable mouseUp can see.
    }

}

// ---------------------------------

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if (myMouseClick) 
    {
        CFTimeInterval deltaTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent () - time;
        if(deltaTime > 2.0)
        {
            // Do your long click action
        }
    }
}
```